# When is it useful to write "0 - x" rather than "-x"?

Tags: c, subtraction, idioms, negative-number

I've occasionally noticed some C code insisting on using `0 - x` to get the additive complement of `x`, rather than writing `-x`. Now, I suppose these are not equivalent for types smaller in size than `int` (**edit**: Nope, apparently equivalent even then), but otherwise - is there some benefit to the former rather than the latter form?

Comment: Actually, being promoted to `int` happens in either case. The only case I see them having a different effect is if `x` is floating-point.

Comment: *"Now, I suppose these are not equivalent for types smaller in size than int"* - They are actually [6.5.3.3p3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.3p3). Which makes this somewhat interesting.

Comment: These days I would just guess readability.  In K&R days maybe they want to avoid `y=-x` where `=-` was an alternative token for `-=`

Comment: As expected, there is a difference for floating-point zero: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc2ec461b152cefc

Comment: Maybe because they want to be sure to get the integer promotion (not knowing that it happens in boths cases)?

Comment: It would be interesting to see where this _occasionally_ comes from.

Comment: If i used it, it would be if it was a mathematical context where I want to make clear that a parameter is zero

Comment: Depending on toolchain, `unsigned int x; x = -x;` may result in a warning, while `unsigned int x; x = 0 - x;` does not. For floating-point types, unary minus is usually mapped to the IEEE-754 "negate" operation, which is a bit-level operation, not an arithmetic operation. So `-x` behaves different from `0 - x` for zero and NaN operands.

Comment: @Deduplicator: That sounds like an answer.

Comment: @RolandIllig: I'm doing some work on a [standalone printf-and-friends implementation](https://github.com/eyalroz/printf/) (forked from [here](https://github.com/mpaland/printf), and it [exhibits this artifact](https://github.com/eyalroz/printf/blob/master/printf.c#L773). I remember seeing this before but I forget where.

Comment: I wonder if the author of that code thought that `0-x` would avoid the bug when `x == LLONG_MIN`.  Unfortunately it does not, and there is UB in that case, whether `0-x` or `-x` is used.  (Your version has the bug too, btw, and for other signed integer types as well.)

Comment: This looks like a private joke... Here are more graphic alternatives: `0-x-0` and `x-x-x` (aka *the winning move*)

Comment: I would say it depends entirely on whether there's a comment on the line of code or not.  *If* there's a comment, and if it says something like `/* We don't want an IEEE-754 -0 here */`, there's your answer.  But if not, I'd assert there's no reason for it at all, and that the original programmer was likely either careless or confused.

Comment: @SteveSummit: No comment :-P

Comment: @NateEldredge: Fixed, albeit in a somewhat brittle kind of way.

Answer (score 4):

#### tl;dr: `0-x` is useful for scrubbing the sign of floating-point zero.

(As @Deduplicator points out in a comment:)

Many of us tend to forget that, in floating-point types, we have both a "positive zero" and a "negative zero" value - flipping the sign bit on and off leaves the same mantissa and exponent. Read more on this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero).

Well, it turns out that the two expressions behave differently on positive-signed zero, and the same on negative-signed zero, as per the following:

| value of `x` | value of `0-x` | value of `-x` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `-.0` | `0` | `0` |
| `0` | `0` | `-.0` |

[See this on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc2ec461b152cefc).

So, when `x` is of a floating-point type,

- If you want to "forget the sign of zero", use `0-x`.
- If you want to "keep the sign of zero", use `x`.

For integer types it shouldn't matter.

---

<sub>On the other hand, as @NateEldredge points out the expressions should be equivalent on small integer types, due to integer promotion -  `-x` translates into  a promotion of `x` into an `int`, then applying the minus sign.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

There is no technical reason to do this today. At least not with integers. And at least not in a way that a sane (according to some arbitrary definition) coder would use. Sure, it could be the case that it causes a cast. I'm actually not 100% sure, but in that case I would use an explicit cast instead to clearly communicate the intention.

As M.M pointed out, there were reasons in the K&R time, when `=-` was equivalent to `-=`. This had the effect that `x=-y` was equivalent to `x=x-y` instead of `x=0-y`. This was undesirable effect, so the feature was removed.

Today, the reason would be readability. Especially if you're writing a mathematical formula and want to point out that a parameter is zero. One example would be the distance formula. The distance from (x,y) to origo is `sqrt(pow(0-x, 2), pow(0-y, 2))`

Comment: That's a good observation about the primordial form of the `-=` operator (and other op-equal operators).  That may very well explain the source of the idiom the OP asks about.